# How to remove circle overlay from leaflet/mapbox map tiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet, mapbox

First off, I'm new to ruby and leaflet.js, I've added a leaflet map onto a view in my ruby project by following the quick start guide on the leaflet site. The map shows up, but is covered in this overlay. This also happened when I was messing  around with Google Maps. How would I go about removing it? I'm running it app locally, would this cause it? Almost positive its something small I'm overlooking. thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could be a [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) CSS rule on all images, like:

```css
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```