# Having mutiple maps on screen using leaflet, want to fix it to single

Tags: leaflet

I used leaftlet to include map in my website, but i am seeing big infinite circles on the screen over map.
CDN used.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
```

JavaScript Code.

```
<!-- map working javascript -->
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=XgEM27Xb3yStMrCCnrfb' , { attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>' }, { noWrap: true }).addTo(map);
        var marker = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map);
        // var layer = new L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        //         noWrap: true
        //     });
    </script>
```

[image: here is the screenshot of the website]

Comment: Screenshot of those "infinite circles", please? And a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the website

Comment: Yeah, you have an aggressive CSS rule applying `border-radius:100%` to all images, and that's leaking into the Leaflet tiles. [Debug your CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS) to locate the problematic rule.

Comment: You have 2 issues: 1) "infinite circles" caused by too generic CSS rule on your page as pointed out by Ivan, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905714/how-to-remove-circle-overlay-from-leaflet-mapbox-map-tiles/38906189?r=SearchResults#38906189. 2) repeating world feature which you do not want. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942988/fit-map-to-bounds-exactly/46969374?r=SearchResults#46969374 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245207/limit-the-zoom-out-in-a-leaflet-map#

Comment: Thanks @ghybs your comment was usefull it worked.